# How hide and show status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

Just it, I have found how to hide title bar but I didnt find how hide / show the status bar pressing a button fr example. It is possible? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a status Bar

Use this code in your Activity

```
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Change Application theme in Manifest file as below

```
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: This does not cover the "show" part of "hide and show".

Answer (score 2):

For poeple whose show part is not working ,  You can try following code

**Show Status Bar**

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
              getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    else {
       View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
      // show the status bar.
       int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
       decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference - https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

```
// This snippet shows the system bars. It does this by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Although action bar is overlayed with the status bar.